# Var_dump changes "something" in my variable?

Tags: php, function, session, token, session-variables

So I am currently coding a user registration in PHP 5.6.10 and just discovered something weird: The function ***Token::check(Input::get('token'))*** returns a boolean. If it returns true, the if-statement is getting executed. Works fine so far, however when I var_dump it previous to the if-statement, the if-statement is not being executed.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour?

```
   var_dump(Token::check(Input::get('token')));

   if(Input::exists()) {       
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {         
        echo "Loop.";
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'first_name' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 1,
                'max' => 50
            )  
        ));


        if($validation->passed()) {
            echo "Die Eingaben waren korrekt.";
        } else {
            foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error,"<br>";
            }
            echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

(I hope I didn't make a typo when shortening the code)
Here is the check()-function as requested:

```
public static function check($token) {
    $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

    if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
        Session::delete($tokenName);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is no "if-loop"! "If" can't loop. When you wan't to do a loop you have to use a "while", "do...while", "for" or "foreach".

Comment: What Token::check does? Maybe the token can't be checked twice?

Comment: @Candyman1332 Yes, you're right. Replaced the word 'loop' with 'statement' in my text.

Comment: @WilliamJanoti It basically checks if there is a session already: `public static function check($token) {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');
        
        if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
            Session::delete($tokenName);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        
    }`

Comment: What happend here: Input::get

Comment: This is called a *side effect* making the function not *idempotent*.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me @deceze! So is what I did there considered bad coding style / bad practice?

Comment: If your function is supposed to always return the same value depending on its input only, and it doesn't in fact do that (it more or less randomly returns some value), then it's either a nonsensical function or a simple bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code from the `check` method:

```
public static function check($token) { 
    $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');  
    if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)){ 
        Session::delete($tokenName); 
        return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

In the first time that you call:

`var_dump(Token::check(Input::get('token')));`

it deletes the token from the session, preventing the condition:

`if(Token::check(Input::get('token')))` to be met.

Maybe you can put an extra param in the check function just to help you debug and not delete the token:

```
 public static function check($token, $test = false) { 
    $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');  
    if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)){ 
        if (!$test) {
            Session::delete($tokenName); 
        }
        return true; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Oh damn, yeah that definitely makes sense.  Should've been able to figure that out myself. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)